# Is delete thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, new-operator, delete-operator

```
int *p = new int;
// delete p in thread 1
// delete p in thread 2
```

I know that make `p` equals to `nullptr` is a good behavior but for now I just want to know if `delete` is thread-safe? Do I need to use lock for the case above?

Yes, I delete the same object twice.

This is because that I found that `delete p` twice in the same thread would make a core dumped error, whereas `delete p` twice in two threads can not make any error.

I know that double delete is an UB so I want to know if `delete` is thread-safe, meaning that if we enter the function `delete` twice at the same time, we are safe because of it is thread-safe.

Comment: Even without threads you can't delete the same object twice.

Comment: Are you deleting `p` twice?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: `I know that double delete is an UB so I want to know if delete is thread-safe, meaning that if we enter the function delete twice at the same time, we are safe because of it is thread-safe.` This is quite the opposite of what thread-safe means. Seems like you have to think harder about __who owns the object__. Alternatively, `std::shared_ptr` is threadsafe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can count on `delete` being as thread-safe as `new`, which, in general, is thread-safe – it may depend on the implementation, e.g.: sometimes you have the choice (or limitation) of using a single-threaded standard library.

However, even if calling `delete` from different threads is safe, calling it with the same pointer value as its argument will result in a *double free*, which is undefined behavior. So, your problem is more about ownership rather than thread safety. You will need to reconsider how ownership works in your program regarding the object whose pointer you are passing twice to `delete`, e.g.:

- Exclusive ownership: one thread owns the object via `std::unique_ptr<T>` and the rest of the threads receive a reference (i.e., `&T`) to the pointee. In this case, you may want none of those non-owning threads to outlive the owning thread.
- Shared ownership: the ownership of the object is shared between multiple threads that have their own copy of a `std::shared_ptr<T>` to the same `T` object.